# Usecases for exclusive queues in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I am new to message queues and was wondering if people can explain usecase(s) for using an exclusive queue in RabbitMQ.

From the docs:

> An exclusive queue can only be used (consumed from, purged, deleted, etc) by its declaring connection.
> Exclusive queues are deleted when their declaring connection is closed or gone. They therefore are only suitable for client-specific transient state

Answer (score 2):

Exclusive queues are a type of [temporary queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#temporary-queues), and as such they:

> "*...can be a reasonable choice for workloads with transient clients, for example, temporary WebSocket connections in user interfaces, mobile applications and devices that are expected to go offline or use switch identities. Such clients usually have inherently transient state that should be replaced when the client reconnects.*"

See notes on [durability](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#temporary-queues) for more context.

Exclusive queues, as you note, have an added restriction. An exclusive queue:

> "*... can only be used (consumed from, purged, deleted, etc) by its declaring connection.*"

This makes it (potentially) suitable for use as queue contained within a single application, where the application will create and then process its own work queue items.

The following points are just my opinion, reflecting on the above notes:

I think it may be a relatively rare RabbitMQ use case, compared to "publish-and-subscribe" use cases such as [topic exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html) and similar implementations which communicate across different nodes and connections.

Also, I would expect that much of the time, the core functionality of this type of queue could be provided by a language's built-in data structures (such as Java's [queue implementations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html)). But if you want a mature out-of-the-box queueing solution for your application to use internally, then maybe it can be a suitable option.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. This confirms my thoughts. With RabbitMQ's decoupled nature, ACK scemantics and transactions I think it has a place above in-built Queue data structures. Once I have the store in place, I could see myself using these Exclusive Queues down the road.